# Fill array with values from for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I am quite new C# and what I am trying to do is fill empty array with values from other array by for cycle. If value from first array meets requirements for second array, then it is filled in.

```
int[] cisla = new int[] {a, b, c, d, e, f}; //first array
    int[] nadprumer = new int[] {}; //second array

    decimal prumer = (a+b+c+d+e+f) / 6;

    for (int i = 0; i< cisla.Length; i++)
    {
        if (cisla[i] > prumer)
        {
            //join value into "nadprumer" array
        }      
    }
```

Comment: Arrays are immutable, you need to use a collection, like `List<int>`. Also, a simpler way to do this is with Linq: `nadprumer = cisla.Where(i => i > prumer).ToArray()`.

Comment: ^ Exactly what I was going to say. Do that.

Comment: @Gusman Arrays are not immutable, you can replace items in the array.  I think you meant array size cannot be changed.

Comment: @juharr Yes, wrong expression, I meant "non resizable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are doing homework or some sort of excercise from the book you read. If they ask you to find all numbers that are greater than their mean then I would do it like that.

First variant (basic level with cycles):

```
int[] cisla = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; //first array            
                       
double prumer = cisla.Average();

List<int> temp = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < cisla.Length; i++)
{
    if (cisla[i] > prumer)
    {
        temp.Add(cisla[i]);
    }
}
int[] nadprumer = temp.ToArray(); //second array
```

Second variant (advanced level with LINQ):

```
int[] cisla = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; //first array            
double prumer = cisla.Average();
int[] nadprumer = cisla.Where(x => x > prumer).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
int[] nadprumer = new int[] {};
```

will create an array of length 0.

What you need to do is:

```
int[] nadprumer = new int[cisla.Length];
```

and then inside your loop:

```
nadprumer[i] = cisla[i];
```

But this will leave the rest as 0. If you don't want that, create a `List<int>` as the target, and then have

```
theList.Add(cisla[i]);
```

in the loop, and if you need the result to be an array, change it to an array in the end like this:

```
theList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

A List type would be allot better like mentioned above - but here it goes.  Maybe this will help?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] cisla = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; //first array type int cannot be strings or characters
            int[] nadprumer = new int[6] ; //second array needs initialized 

            decimal prumer = (cisla[0] + cisla[1] + cisla[2] + cisla[3] + cisla[4] + cisla[5]) / 6;//why do you need this?

            for (int i = 0; i < cisla.Length; i++)
            {
                //if (cisla[i] > prumer)//why are you doing this?
                //{
                    //join value into "nadprumer" array
                    nadprumer[i] = cisla[i];
                    Console.WriteLine(nadprumer[i]);
                    
                //}
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```